# Cannot Array.filter properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Despite of numerous thread on the subject I didn't manage to remove an item of a string based Array using `Array.filter` method. Here is the filter method in a context of a mutation of a Vuex store.

```
UPDATE_FILTERS_GEOLOGIES: (state, payload) => {
  if (state.filters.geologies.some(elem => elem === payload)) {
    state.filters.geologies.filter(elem => !elem.includes(payload))
  } else {
    state.filters.geologies.push(payload);
  }
}
```

The filter method is call but the item is not removed. I ended up using `Array.splice` method:

```
let position = state.filters.geologies.indexOf(payload);
state.filters.geologies.splice(position, 1)
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `filter` does not mutate the original array.

Comment: As @CertainPerformance said, try `state.filters.geologies = state.filters.geologies.filter(elem => !elem.includes(payload))`

Comment: Not this way Cristian. This way the `state.filters.geologies` becomes not reactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on MDN:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

so basically what is wrong in your code is that:

`state.filters.geologies.filter(elem => !elem.includes(payload))`

is not being saved in any variable, thus the filtered array isn't being used. in order to make it work you need to assign the return value of the `filter`. something like:

`state.filters.geologies = state.filters.geologies.filter(elem => !elem.includes(payload))`

or as vladislav said:

```
state.filters.geologies = [...state.filters.geologies.filter(elem => !elem.includes(payload))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Until splice() method is mutating original array, filter(), map(), or some() methods returns new array and leave the original array intact. So, you can use filter() method, but then you should replace original array with returned array. For example:

```
UPDATE_FILTERS_GEOLOGIES: (state, payload) => {
  let g = state.filter.geologies
  let p = payload

  g.some(e => e === p)
    ? (g = { ...g.filter(e => !e.includes(p)) })
    : g.push(p)
}
```